# How to get all NFT(Non Fungible Token) which created on the specific smart contract of the Tezos blockchain?(getNftForContract)

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, blockchain, nft

I have a smart contract address and I want to get the list of all NFTs that exist on this smart contract!

***The goal is to get all NFTs data (Like its address, its visual, and its value) with the same smart contract of the Tezos blockchain.***

> Is there any API or library which helps to achieve this?

I don't find any useful document at [tezos wiki](https://wiki.tezos.com/).

I want to use it inside a Flutter project finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at https://github.com/teia-community/teia-docs/wiki/Tools-made-by-the-community#open-indexers

You can also try https://api.tzkt.io/#tag/Tokens